# angular/cdk simple drag not working for div with ngFor

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, drag, ngfor, angular-cdk

I need to make an item draggable with angular-cdk. I have imported the DragDropModule in the app module. I am applying the cdkDrag inside an ngFor.

```
<div *ngIf="messages.length" >
    <div
      *ngFor="let message of messages" cdkDrag>
      <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The drag is not working as expected, also no errors are appearing in the console. The drag feature works for normal div elements.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In addition to [M. Doe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5409086/m-doe)'s answer, I had to do the following:

Add the following to my app.module.ts file:

```
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
...
imports:
[
    DragDropModule
]
```

Add the cdkDropListData parameter to my parent element that contains the list of items to sort:

```
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="messages" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event) *ngIf="messages.length" >
    <div
      *ngFor="let message of messages" cdkDrag>
      <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was my issue as well. However, shouldn't there be an error thrown if the module isn't properly imported?

Answer (score 12):

You should add `cdkDropList` to your outer div, aswell as a drop event.

[Drag and drop CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview).

**component.html**

```xml
<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" *ngIf="messages.length" >
    <div
      *ngFor="let message of messages" cdkDrag>
      <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**component.ts**

```js
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.messages, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
```

Comment: what is moveItemInArray()

Comment: I got it. thank you ; import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/qvqgjgajjeq?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html

Remove the `strong` tag so the div is the looped child. Then add the font-weight: 700 to the div class to replicate a strong class

Answer (score 2):

1. You should add DragDropModule into module where the component is declared
2. The *ngFor directive works with cdkDrag directive without cdkDropList

Answer (score 1):

Removing `class` attribute from cdkDrag element fixed drag drop in my case.